# Bootstrap Carousel - not cycling at all

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

So my problem is with carousel as in title.

I checked quite few solutions until now, re-write whole section with carousel like 5 times and problem is still the same:

Carousel shows only 1 (active) item, it doesn't cycle and when you click on one of the indicators it just drops about 200px (looks like "scroll on click" to me).

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="img/nauka-jazdy-luton-1.jpg" alt="Slide1">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/nauka-jazdy-luton-2.jpg" alt="Slide2">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/nauka-jazdy-luton-3.jpg" alt="Slide3">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<sctipt>$("#carousel").carousel();</sctipt>
```

And CSS:

```
.carousel {
    height: 250px;
}

.carousel .item {
    width: auto;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #878787;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Have you included bootstrap.min.js in your project?

Comment: Typo with `<sctipt>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend found an answer for this and it was the latest version of jQuery.
I am using version of Bootstrap which does not support jQuery from v3 on.

Now carousel works without any problems!
I hope someone will find this post useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxraKr

Looks like you forgot to include bootstrap.min.js

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Add this line above your JQuery.
Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you for your help but it's still not working.
I really have no clue what's going on with this, as I look at examples like code pen you sent it all should work but... Just have a look please:

[link](http://maciekjarmula.usermd.net)

Comment: You've added Jquery after bootstrap. Include the jquery script before the bootstrap script. Please make this as the answer for others if it helps you. Cheers

Comment: Additionally your script tag for initializing the carousel is misspelled as sctipt instead of script